# How to bypass y/n questions in cmd while using popen()

Tags: c++, c, cmd, popen

Today I have been facing a critical bug in my program, it is just a tiny code that uses popen() to pass the commands and pipe its results to a file descriptor where I use `fgets()` to read the result, The problem for `date` command my program is been hanging(waiting) and the reason is as we know after issuing `date` it will show the current date and issues a yes or no question like the below.

> The current date is: Fri 08/21/2015
>   Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)----this was shitting my code!!!!

I just want my program to skip this questionnaire.

Note: the string "command" in the below code is what I will receive from the user.

```
FILE *in;
char buff[512];
string cmd;
command += " 2>&1";
if (!(in = popen(command.c_str(), "r"))) {
    status = "0"; // my logic don't bother:)
}
else {
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL) {
        cmd += buff;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `date /t` to get it to display the date only, without prompting for input. Should work from XP onwards. The only confusion I have here is that you're using `2>&1`, which seems to imply a posix shell, which isn't really in `cmd`'s list of features.

Comment: You are closing `in` within the while loop. Are you sure that's what you want?

If so remove the loop as it is unecessary, otherwise move the close behind the loop.

I have no idea what happens when you call fgets on a closed file handle.

Comment: And please correct your comment and intention. It's not the easiest to be read the way it is.

Comment: Hi petesh, thanks much!! for your reply the problem is the command which ask y/n question is not limited to "Date" if suppose the user pass "del **.** /q" it hungs. and for your question, 2>&1 is not limited to posix it works in windows too since i have been using  MinGW.

Comment: Hi simon,thanks it was accidentally copied and i edited it too!!!!

Comment: You're right about the redirection; It's been a while. you can redirect input from nul - e.g. `command += "2>&1 <nul"`, which should work for most dos command to take the default.

Comment: Just asking: why? I mean, what is this code trying to achieve? Executing any user-supplied command, that is often a bad idea. Either you try creating your own shell (which would require a LOT more effort) or maybe you want to have some "configurable" actions, then just feeding `/dev/null` (or `NUL` on windows) for `stdin` is probably the best idea, but I wouldn't use `popen()` in either case, you have too little control on error conditions...

Comment: Hi felix, we just have bunch of users who want to monitor the XP systems like taking their ipconfig, listing directory, del,remove and more, but i am not really sure about configurable stuff you have mentioned.

Comment: Petesh!!!!!!!!!! command += "2>&1 <nul" its worked thanks much, if you don't mind may i know what it is or does? i am sure about "2>&1" but not about "2>&1<nul"

Comment: While as a general question this has a reasonable answer, for the date command the answer is simple: don't use `popen` and `date` at all. There are perfectly good `time` and `localtime` functions that give you the result portably, and in a format you can already use, rather than requiring complex system-specific hacks to run `date`, control it, and parse its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Petesh.

I have changed to `2>&1<nul` instead of `2>&1`, the program isn't hanging now,
The key to this solution is adding `<nul` gives some default value as an answer to the prompts.